# Grafana Graph default Initial Value

Tags: graph, grafana

Our requirement is to set the `yAxis label` to a default value. Let's say 0, which should be the minimum to the grid. Values should not go below 0 to negative. How do I achieve that? It is okay that the line of graph can be on the bottom if the data points are 0.

There are files which can be edited - `app.js`, `axisEditor.html` and many others to achieve this, but out of many functions which should be edited to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I got the answer. While exploring I got an option in the edit menu where I can set grid max and min value for the graph.